# ¿Is there any alternative for req.files in NodeJS v0.12.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I need to upload a CSV file for later storage in the database, and this with Angularjs and NodeJS, but due the company restrictions in the project we are using NodeJS v0.12.5 and req.files is not supported. Do you know an altenative or workaround to do the same?

Comment: Probably this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Thanks in fact someone recommended me to use busboy, and multer has embedded busboy.